# Backup and Restore older version of Geoserver 2.6

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I am currently still running Geoserver version 2.6 and would like to find tools to backup and restore. is there any recommended tools or ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded the geoserver to 2.16 and there is a plugin where I could backup and restore the configuration I did in the Geoserver.